# Convert X-Y coordinates to latitude and longitude - python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, latitude-longitude

I have a dataframe with columns which contain x coordinates and y coordinates. I want to converted those to their respective latitude and longitude values. I have been reading up but could not find a set of formulae to work with. 
I am working with python. I am working with the 311 calls open dataset for the city of San Antonio.
Can someone guide me on how to convert x, y coordinates to latitudes and longitudes? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post some sample input and output?

Comment: First we need to know the coordinate system from the X,Y coordinates. For example, California State Plane Coordinate System?

Answer (score 2):

```
def xy_to_lonlat(x, y):
    proj_latlon = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong',datum='WGS84')
    proj_xy = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone=33, datum='WGS84')
    lonlat = pyproj.transform(proj_xy, proj_latlon, x, y)
    return lonlat[0], lonlat[1]
```

this function should do the work.
If you want  to do a reverse transformation use this:

```
def lonlat_to_xy(lon, lat):
proj_latlon = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong',datum='WGS84')
proj_xy = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone=33, datum='WGS84')
xy = pyproj.transform(proj_latlon, proj_xy, lon, lat)
return xy[0], xy[1]
```

Comment: this is a sample input and output. However, this will work for north Europ you need to know the coordinate system from the X,Y coordinates.